# How to store a 32-bit integer in an arraybuffer?

Tags: javascript, uint8array

I seem to not be understanding the `Uint32Array`. According to what I've read about the `Uint8Array` I could just feed it a number inside an array (`Uint8Array([16])` or `Uint8Array([96,56])`) and the results are exactly that. However, when I try the same thing for a larger number like `Uint32Array([21640])`, it seems to truncate it. Where 21640 should equal 5488 in hex, I only get 88. How does this actually work?

**Edit: Elaborations**

I am also attempting to concatenate several ArrayBuffers together. If I'm not mistaken `readAsArrayBuffer` produces an `Uint8Array`, and I am trying to append to that some 32-bit numbers using https://gist.github.com/72lions/4528834

There is so much information and examples on `Uint8Array` and what little there was on `Uint32Array` makes me think that one of these 32 would store a value as if it was 4 of the 8.

Comment: "It seems"? It *is*, because you can't fit 32 bits into 8. You need to break it up.

Comment: @DaveNewton Any suggestions on how to break it up into `Uint8Array(4)` so it becomes `88 54 00 00`?

Comment: It is working fine. Must be something wrong with your hex printing routine only handling byte. Without showing any code it is not possible to be certain that this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest value of an unsigned 8 bit number is 255. Larger numbers will be truncated or rolled over depending on the os/cpu. If you want to convert a 32 bit numbers in an 8 bit array try something like this.

```
var number = 21640;
var byte1 = 0xff & number;
var byte2 = 0xff & (number >> 8);
var byte3 = 0xff & (number >> 16);
var byte4 = 0xff & (number >> 24);

var arr1 = Uint8Array([byte1,byte2,byte3,byte4]);
```

Just reverse the order of the bytes when you create the array depending on if you want little or big endian.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example showing 5488 in console

```
    var bigNumber = new Uint32Array([21640]);
    console.log(bigNumber[0].toString(16));
```

Since you've added more to the question. If you wanted to convert

```
var byte1 = 0x88;
var byte2 = 0x54;
var byte3 = 0;
var byte4 = 0;

var bigValue = (byte4 << 24) | (byte3 << 16) | (byte2 << 8) | (byte1);

console.log(bigValue);
```

Although you will need to factor in Endianness